# Numpy I/O: convert % percentage to float between 0 and 1

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5, converters

## The thing I want to do:

**Convert string representing percentage xx% to a float between 0 and 1**

## My code:

```
#a. general case
data = "1, 2.3%, 45.\n6, 78.9%, 0"
names = ("i", "p", "n")
a = np.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(data.encode()), names = names, delimiter = ",")
print (a)           # returns [(1.0, nan, 45.0) (6.0, nan, 0.0)]
print (a.dtype)     # reason: default dtype is float, cannot convert 2.3%, 78.9%


#b. converter case
convertfunc = lambda x: float(x.strip("%"))/100     # remove % and   return the value in float (between 0 and 1)
b = np.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(data.encode()), names = names, delimiter = ",", converters = {1:convertfunc})  # use indices for 2nd column as key and do the conversion
print (b)
print (b.dtype)
```

## My problem:

In the general case, the percentage in % will be printed as nan. Since the fault dtype is float, percentage in % cannot be converted. Thus, I tried the converter method.

However, when I run the code, error occurs:

```
convertfunc = lambda x: float(x.strip("%"))/100     # remove % and return the value in float (between 0 and 1)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Anyone knows what's the problem here? (I am using python3.5)

Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't split a *bytes-like* object with a `str` object viz `'%'`. Append a `b` to the start of the *strip* string to make it a bytes object.

```
convertfunc = lambda x: float(x.strip(b"%"))/100
#                                     ^

b = np.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(data.encode()), names = names, delimiter = ",", converters = {1:convertfunc})

print(b)
# array([(1.0, 0.023, 45.0), (6.0, 0.789, 0.0)],
# dtype=[('i', '<f8'), ('p', '<f8'), ('n', '<f8')])
```

---

Such objects with a leading `b` belong to the `bytes` class:

```
>>> type('%')
<class 'str'>
>>> type(b'%')
<class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That really answered my question.